# how to read a document library file's stream and write to a new file in local system?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I would download files from document library recursively and bundle them to ZIP. I tried to achieve in the below code. However I get an error in OpenBinaryDirect as "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.".

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File fl = splistItem.File;
var stream = fl.OpenBinaryStream();
var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(Context, fl.ServerRelativeUrl);
var fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\", fl.Title);
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
{
    fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

What should be the possible error? Guess it is a credentials issue, however not particularly sure on this. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Set the credential for context.

sample code:

online:

```
    string siteUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/TST";
                string userName = "lee@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
                string password = "pw";

                using (var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
                {
                    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
                    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
//read file
}
```

on-premise:

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pwd", "domain");

ClientContext context = new ClientContext(“http://thesitecollection”);

context.Credentials = credentials;
```